# How to transform this code from using double await to one await for lazy loading import

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

I'm using Svelte and Protobuf generated clients.

In `./generated/index.ts` I'm using this code:

```
import type { PlayerServiceClient } from './proto/player.client';

const transport = new GrpcWebFetchTransport({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api' });

let playerService: PlayerServiceClient;
export const player = async (): Promise<PlayerServiceClient> =>
    playerService ||
    ((playerService = new (await import('./player.client')).PlayerServiceClient(transport)),
    playerService);
```

which is why I'm using the below code that I don't like because is too verbose, DRY and long:

```
import { player } from "../generated";

let players: Player[];

(async () => {
  const playerService = await player();
  const { response } = await playerService.queryPlayers({ playerId: "1" });

  if (response) {
    players = response.players;
  }
})();
```

**QUESTION**:

Is there a way to still have lazy `import()` but without the verbose double `await` in each component?

I would like to have this code instead:

```
import { player } from "../generated";

let players: Player[];

(async () => {
  players = await player.queryPlayers({ playerId: "1" });
})();
```

**Additional context**:

I have many different types (and therefore services) (hundreds) and many different navigation routes: this is why I need lazy load.

Comment: With top level `await` you could just `export const player = await ...;`

Comment: Oh, thanks. But I don't understand. Can you write more, please?